# C# Winform ToolTip Enable/Disable

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am trying to give the user an option to disable and enable the tool tips.
In my application, I created a menu strip with two options (EnableToolTip/DisableToolTip).
Here my code to set the tool Tips (where ttObj is a global object):

```
private void loadToolTips()
{

    ttObj.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
    ttObj.InitialDelay = 1000;
    ttObj.ReshowDelay = 500;

    ttObj.SetToolTip(this.btnSetRolesType, "A");
    ttObj.SetToolTip(btnCreateUser, "B");
    ttObj.SetToolTip(btnModifyNum, "C");
    ttObj.SetToolTip(btnFindDups, "D");
    ttObj.ShowAlways = false;

}
```

And this is where I am trying to disable the tooltips

```
private void enableToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    enableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    disableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
}

private void disableToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    disableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    enableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
    ttObj.Hide(this); //this doesn't do anything

}
```

There isn't much on google or stackoverflow. Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the enable menuitem doesn't do much either.  Just *dispose* the tooltip, create it when it is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable/disable the tool tips, use the [`Active`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.active(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Set it `False` to disable and when you set it back to `True`, you'll have your tool tips again without having to re-add them.

```
private void enableToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    enableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    disableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;

    ttObj.Active = true;
}

private void disableToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    disableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    enableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;

    ttObj.Active = false;
}
```

Alternatively, to just wipe them out, use [`RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.removeall(v=vs.110).aspx). You'll have to re-run `loadToolTips()` to add them back.

```
private void disableToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    disableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    enableToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;

    ttObj.RemoveAll();   
}
```

Comment: I guess when I enable them i have rebuild by running the rebuildtoolTip method?